# Is there a way to pre-build all of my services that are registered with the Simple Injector container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I am trying to improve the initial request time of my server right after deployment or restart by the IIS Manager. As I was looking for a way to do that I came across this article *[Reducing initial request latency by pre-building services in a startup task in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/reducing-latency-by-pre-building-singletons-in-asp-net-core/)*. However, my project uses the [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/) (SI) library - I am not sure how (if it's even possible) to instruct SI to pre-build my registered services which should improve the first request time.

Has anyone tried that before?

That is my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private static readonly Container _container = new Container();

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.Configure<AzureBlobSettings>(settings =>
            Configuration.GetSection("AzureBlobSettings").Bind(settings));

        IntegrateSimpleInjector(services);
    }

    private void IntegrateSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
            new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(_container));
        services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(
            new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(_container));

        services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(_container);
        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(_container);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        InitializeContainer(app, env);

        // standard config

        _container.Verify();

        // standard config

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "openSpotfire",
                template:
                "{controller=OpenAnalytics}/{action=AnalyticsView}/{id?}/{name?}"
                );
        });
    }

    private void InitializeContainer(
        IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Add application presentation components:
        _container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
        _container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

        // Add application services. 
        ServiceConfiguration.ConfigureService(_container, Configuration, env);

        // Allow Simple Injector to resolve services from ASP.NET Core.
        _container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app);
    }
}
```

That is my `ServiceConfiguration.cs`

```
public static class ServiceConfiguration
{
    public static void ConfigureService(
        Container c, IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //Cross Cutting Concerns from nuget
        container.Register<CurrentUser>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IUserProfileService, CachedUserProfileService>(
                Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<ISharedItemBuilderFactory, SharedItemBuilderFactory>(
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IEmailer, DbMailer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IRecipientService, RecipientService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<ISpotfireUserDataService, SpotfireUserDataService>(
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IWorkbookManagementService, WorkbookManagementService>(
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<ILogger, NLogLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        // CCC Settings
        container.Register(() => new DbMailConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = configuration["AppSettings:ConnectionString"],
            Profile = configuration["AppSettings:DbMailProfile"]
        }, Lifestyle.Singleton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that the method described by Andrew Lock to iterate the ServiceCollection can easily break down and prevent your application from starting, because you will find that framework and third-party registrations are sometimes made in a partial correct state, and are made complete based on user configuration. ServiceCollection registrations are not required to be correct, making it tricky to iterate the ServiceCollection. It might work at first, but break down later after updating packages or adding new ones.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Steven! At first glance the method Andrew suggested seemed like a very good idea but now I am leaning towards not touching my current configuration :)

Comment: Pre-building the ServiceCollection: bad idea. Pre-building Simple Injector: perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [is it possible] to instruct SI to pre-build my registered services which should improve the first request time.

Yes, there is. **You should call `Container.Verify()` after you configured the container.**

Among other things, verify iterates through all known registrations, creates and compiles their expression trees.

By default, `Verify` does a number of things:

- It builds all expression trees for all registrations
- It compiles those expression trees into delegates
- It calls those delegates to ensure the instances can be created. With this, it forces the JIT compiler to compile the delegates
- It will iterate container-controlled collections, as they behave as streams in Simple Injector
- It will ensure decoratees are created in case the decorator contains a decoratee factory.
- It will run full diagnostics on your object graph

There is an overload of `Verify` available that allows you to suppress the last, diagnostics step. But do note that you should typically not suppress diagnostics.

Besides reducing the time it takes to execute the first few requests, calling verify is advised, because it checks the health of your configuration by running the diagnostic services. This is a unique feature that separates Simple Injector from all other DI Containers for .NET.

For more information, see the documentation [Verify the container’s configuration](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#verify-configuration) and on [diagnostics](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I didn't realise that `verify` does all that, I actually didn't expect it because of the name of the method. I guess I should've checked the docs for that method first :)

Comment: Having `verify()` as fixed part of our startup routines saved us many times from potentially nasty problems. Should be a standard feature on all DI containers.

Answer (score 3):

The article you linked just creates an instance of each service on startup, regardless of whether it's singleton, scoped or transient.

**Edit: Removed code because there is a way better solution**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183491/928483

Comment: Three notes about your solution: 1. This code will likely not work unless you wrap the operation in an active scope. 2. When you have called `container.Verify()`, there is *no* need in doing this loop anylonger, because this is one of the things that Verify actually did. 3. Your solution will not compile everything, as, for instance, collections are still lazily read. `Verify`, on the other hand, ensures that registered collections will be compiled and tested as well.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, can't believe I didn't think about the scope bit because this is in startup code and not a request. Never considered what the `Verify` call does internally, tbh.